# Translate field values from Italian to English

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I want to convert the dataset for 19th century factories from Italian to English. I was thinking about typing it out in the Field Calculator like so (note the Classe column needs to be converted and is shown in the attribute table to the left):

[image]

However, this is time consuming to input. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Have you had a look at the "more info" link at the bottom, to the right of the red error message? I suggest you replace the `=` with `LIKE`. Also, why do you feel this is time consuming?

Comment: Because I need to edit the current names as well as the new names inside the formula, the total list of names is around 30. I would much rather pair the old and new names, which may perhaps be possible with the modeler? Replacing = with Like, unfortunately does not make a difference.

Comment: It seems you have forget a quote after "Mill"?

Comment: I guess @Christophe_P. is right. However, when posting code/expressions, post it as text and not as screenshot: this helps finding errors. Otherwise, people who want to test it have to re-type it (if you already complain about time-consuming typing). There for sure are ways to pair the corresponding words, like using key:value pairs (maps, dictionary-type), but if you're not familiar with it, it is probably faster doing it the way you started with. You can easily copy your when/then lines and just change the italien/english name, I don't see why that should be more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution will be to made a join between your datas with the factories in italian and a list that contain the traductions.

You can product a list of unique italian value with the algorithm "list unique value'. Than you can add a field for the translation. And finaly make a join.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was after!